# Call Jquery function on Input tag having data-slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, adminlte, bootstrap-slider

I am using ready made template provided by *AdminLTE Bootstrap Admin Dashboard Template*. I have following slider input at html page & want to call jquery event on slider

```
<div class="price-range"><!--price-range-->
  <h2>Price Range</h2>
  <div class="well text-center">
    <input type="text" class="span2" value="" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="600" data-slider-step="5" data-slider-value="[250,450]" id="sl2" ><br />
    <b id="min" class="pull-left">$ 0</b>
    <b id="max" class="pull-right">$ 600</b>
  </div>
</div><!--/price-range-->
```

It looks like,

[image]

How can I call event when I slide value in it?

I tried following but not working,

```
$(document).on('blur change click dblclick error focus focusin focusout hover keydown keypress keyup load mousedown mouseenter mouseleave mousemove mouseout mouseover mouseup resize scroll select submit', '#sl2', function() {
  alert("hii")
});
```

Comment: Depending on the plugin you're using the event may not be raised on the original input, but on the plugin instance itself. I'd suggest referring to their documentation

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I got your point, I need to inspect it more deep, I will delete or update question soon once I do it.

Comment: I recon that the plugin which you use does no bother to actually trigger the change event in code. If Javascript changes an input value, the change event is not triggered naturally! Only user input triggers the natural change event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [bootstrap-slider doc](https://www.javascripting.com/view/bootstrap-slider) you have to handle 'slideStop' event. Y've preapred a sample [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Dganenco/qaozLtmc/) for you.

```
const slider = $('#ex1').slider({
  formatter: function(value) {
    return 'Current value: ' + value;
  }
});

slider.on('slideStop', function(e) {
  console.log('value = ' + e.value);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for edit in question & answer with sample example. It works like charm :) I am not that good in front end.